# how to get request code from an intent object android

Tags: java, android

can anyone tell how can we get the ***requestcode*** from an **Intent** which we passed from another activity??

Comment: An `Intent` does not have a "request code" (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Do you mean an `Intent` extra?

Comment: The requestCode used when creating a pendingIntent is not intended to pass on to the receiver, it is intended as a way for the app creating the pendingIntent to be able to manage multiple pendingIntents.  

Suppose an alarm app needed to create several pendingIntents, and later needs to cancel or modify one of them.  The requestCode is used to identify which one to cancel/modify.  

To pass data on, use the putExtra as described below.  Note you might very well want to use RowId for both the requestCode and the Extra data.

Answer (score 9):

If you do

```
intent.putExtra("requestCode", requestCode);
```

You can get it by doing:

```
int requestCode = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("requestCode");
```

Or

If you do startActivityForResult like this:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

The request code is there as parameter:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```